# No mremap for windows?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-memory

As I understand it, to reserve a chunk of virtual memory in linux, you call `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_PRIVATE`, and the equivalent system call on windows is `VirtualAlloc`.

However, linux provides `mremap` to resize a memory mapping, which the man page says

> changes the mapping between virtual addresses and memory pages

I cannot find an equivalent system call for windows. It seems that to reallocate memory, it is necessary to use `HeapAlloc` instead of `VirtualAlloc`, and then use `HeapReAlloc`. Regarding `HeapReAlloc`, msdn says

> The process of preserving the memory content involves a memory copy operation that is potentially very time-consuming.

So is there no way of remapping pieces of virtual memory in Windows? If not, why not?

Comment: Using `CreateFilemapping` on a null handle followed by `MapViewOfFile` is much closer to calling `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS`. Using `MapViewOfFileEx` and specifying the same address is as close to `mremap` as you can get in Win32. Though of course you could use `VirtualAllocEx` too, if you insist on using that. In any case you have no guarantee whatsoever that you get back the same address (not under Linux either!) so I guess getting as close as possible does not matter much.

Comment: Slight correction: You can actually get better behaviour under Windows. If you reserve a large enough portion of address space first, you can commit it later, and you're guaranteed that it's at the same location. Still, it's not exactly the same (but... probably even better).

Comment: Getting the same address isn't important, but not actually copying the data (ie just remapping the physical pages) is the goal.

Comment: Reserving first (`MEM_RESERVE`) then committing what you actually need (`MEMCOMMIT`) later will give you exactly that. Only thing to watch out is running out of address space under 32bit, if it's hundreds of MBs you need (no issue under 64bit, obviously).

Answer (score 3):

Fine-grained control of virtual memory on Windows may be achieved through the AWE-family of functions in the Win32 API.

Initial allocation is done with [AllocateUserPhysicalPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366528(v=vs.85).aspx), which,  as the name alludes to, allocates actual physical pages for you. You may then proceed to map these physical pages to virtual pages using [MapUserPhysicalPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366753(v=vs.85).aspx) into a virtual address space range that you have previously reserved using `VirtualAlloc`. Note that you may remap an already mapped physical page to a different virtual page.

This does come with a different set of semantics as you are dealing with both physical and virtual memory at the same time. Among a few of the drawbacks that may be worth mentioning are that you need to ensure that there is *no aliasing* present; and that you are effectively restricted to using the native page size, i.e. you will not be able to use large pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution using Address Windowing Extensions (AWE).
The idea is to temporarily map the starting physical pages to the end of the virtual memory. In order to do this, you have to virtually allocate twice the size of the cyclic array.

It is not as convenient as Linux mremap, but it works.
Regarding the MSDN documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualalloc2), you could also use "placeholders" with VirtualAlloc2, but it is only available on Windows 10 and later.

This solution is based on the MSDN example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366531(v=vs.85).aspx). Please remember to get the "lock page in memory" privilege for your account in Windows before running it.

```cpp
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    
    #define MEMORY_REQUESTED 1024*1024 // request a megabyte
    
    BOOL
    LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege ( HANDLE hProcess,
                                  BOOL bEnable);
    
    BOOL
    CyclicMapUserPhysicalPages( void* VirtualAddress,
                                void* VirtualHeadAddress,
                                ULONG_PTR NumberOfPages,
                                ULONG_PTR* PageArray,
                                DWORD dwPageSize);
    
    void _cdecl main()
    {
      BOOL bResult;                   // generic Boolean value
      ULONG_PTR NumberOfPages;        // number of pages to request
      ULONG_PTR NumberOfPagesInitial; // initial number of pages requested
      ULONG_PTR *aPFNs;               // page info; holds opaque data
      PVOID lpMemReserved;            // AWE window
      SYSTEM_INFO sSysInfo;           // useful system information
      int PFNArraySize;               // memory to request for PFN array
    
      GetSystemInfo(&sSysInfo);  // fill the system information structure
    
      _tprintf(_T("This computer has page size %d.\n"), sSysInfo.dwPageSize);
    
      // Calculate the number of pages of memory to request.
    
      NumberOfPages = MEMORY_REQUESTED/sSysInfo.dwPageSize;
      _tprintf (_T("Requesting %d pages of memory.\n"), NumberOfPages);
    
      // Calculate the size of the user PFN array.
    
      PFNArraySize = NumberOfPages * sizeof (ULONG_PTR);
    
      _tprintf (_T("Requesting a PFN array of %d bytes.\n"), PFNArraySize);
    
      aPFNs = (ULONG_PTR *) HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, PFNArraySize);
    
      if (aPFNs == NULL)
      {
        _tprintf (_T("Failed to allocate on heap.\n"));
        return;
      }
    
      // Enable the privilege.
    
      if( ! LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege( GetCurrentProcess(), TRUE ) )
      {
        return;
      }
    
      // Allocate the physical memory.
    
      NumberOfPagesInitial = NumberOfPages;
      bResult = AllocateUserPhysicalPages( GetCurrentProcess(),
                                           &NumberOfPages,
                                           aPFNs );
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot allocate physical pages (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
        return;
      }
    
      if( NumberOfPagesInitial != NumberOfPages )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("Allocated only %p pages.\n"), NumberOfPages );
        return;
      }
    
      // Reserve the virtual memory.
    
      lpMemReserved = VirtualAlloc( NULL,
                                    MEMORY_REQUESTED*2, // NB: Twice the size
                                    MEM_RESERVE | MEM_PHYSICAL,
                                    PAGE_READWRITE );
    
      if( lpMemReserved == NULL )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot reserve memory.\n"));
        return;
      }
    
      // Cyclic Map the physical memory into the window.
      void* Head = ((char*)lpMemReserved) + MEMORY_REQUESTED - 6; // Arbitrary Head Address (must be between >= lpMemReserved and <lpMemReserved+MEMORY_REQUESTED)
      bResult = CyclicMapUserPhysicalPages( lpMemReserved,
                                            Head,
                                            NumberOfPages,
                                            aPFNs,
                                            sSysInfo.dwPageSize );
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("CyclicMapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
        return;
      }
    
      sprintf((char*)Head, "Hello World");
    
      /// unmap Cyclic
      bResult = CyclicMapUserPhysicalPages( lpMemReserved,
                                            Head,
                                            NumberOfPages,
                                            NULL,
                                            sSysInfo.dwPageSize );
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("CyclicMapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
        return;
      }
    
      // Map the physical memory into the window.
    
      bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages( lpMemReserved,
                                      NumberOfPages,
                                      aPFNs );
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("MapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
        return;
      }
    
      if (strcmp((char const*)lpMemReserved, "World"))
      {
        _tprintf(_T("Mem Content Check failed\n") );
        return;
      }
    
      // unmap
    
      bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages( lpMemReserved,
                                      NumberOfPages,
                                      NULL );
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("MapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
        return;
      }
    
      // Free the physical pages.
    
      bResult = FreeUserPhysicalPages( GetCurrentProcess(),
                                       &NumberOfPages,
                                       aPFNs );
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot free physical pages, error %u.\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
      }
    
      // Free virtual memory.
    
      bResult = VirtualFree( lpMemReserved,
                             0,
                             MEM_RELEASE );
    
      // Release the aPFNs array.
    
      bResult = HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, aPFNs);
    
      if( bResult != TRUE )
      {
          _tprintf(_T("Call to HeapFree has failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
      }
    
    }
    
    /*****************************************************************
       LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege: a function to obtain or
       release the privilege of locking physical pages.
    
       Inputs:
    
           HANDLE hProcess: Handle for the process for which the
           privilege is needed
    
           BOOL bEnable: Enable (TRUE) or disable?
    
       Return value: TRUE indicates success, FALSE failure.
    
    *****************************************************************/
    BOOL
    LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege ( HANDLE hProcess,
                                  BOOL bEnable)
    {
      struct {
        DWORD Count;
        LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privilege [1];
      } Info;
    
      HANDLE Token;
      BOOL Result;
    
      // Open the token.
    
      Result = OpenProcessToken ( hProcess,
                                  TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
                                  & Token);
    
      if( Result != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf( _T("Cannot open process token.\n") );
        return FALSE;
      }
    
      // Enable or disable?
    
      Info.Count = 1;
      if( bEnable )
      {
        Info.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
      }
      else
      {
        Info.Privilege[0].Attributes = 0;
      }
    
      // Get the LUID.
    
      Result = LookupPrivilegeValue ( NULL,
                                      SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME,
                                      &(Info.Privilege[0].Luid));
    
      if( Result != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf( _T("Cannot get privilege for %s.\n"), SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME );
        return FALSE;
      }
    
      // Adjust the privilege.
    
      Result = AdjustTokenPrivileges ( Token, FALSE,
                                       (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) &Info,
                                       0, NULL, NULL);
    
      // Check the result.
    
      if( Result != TRUE )
      {
        _tprintf (_T("Cannot adjust token privileges (%u)\n"), GetLastError() );
        return FALSE;
      }
      else
      {
        if( GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS )
        {
          _tprintf (_T("Cannot enable the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege; "));
          _tprintf (_T("please check the local policy.\n"));
          return FALSE;
        }
      }
    
      CloseHandle( Token );
    
      return TRUE;
    }
    
    /*
     --->(tail)         (head) ----- ~~~~>
          v              v
    +-------------------------------|-------------------------------+
    |                        virtual memory                         |
    +-------------------------------|-------------------------------+
    <--- Memory Requested Size ---->
    */
    BOOL CyclicMapUserPhysicalPages(void* VirtualAddress, void* VirtualHeadAddress, ULONG_PTR NumberOfPages, ULONG_PTR* PageArray, DWORD dwPageSize){
      ULONG_PTR iStartPage = (ULONG_PTR(VirtualHeadAddress)-ULONG_PTR(VirtualAddress))/dwPageSize;
    
      void* pEnd = ((BYTE*)VirtualAddress)+dwPageSize*iStartPage;
      void* pStart = ((BYTE*)VirtualAddress)+dwPageSize*NumberOfPages;
      BOOL bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages( pEnd, NumberOfPages-iStartPage, PageArray ? (PageArray+iStartPage) : NULL );
      if( !bResult )
        return FALSE;
    
      if (iStartPage)
      {
        bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages( pStart, iStartPage, PageArray );
        if( !bResult ){
          if (PageArray)
            MapUserPhysicalPages( pEnd, NumberOfPages-iStartPage, NULL );
          return FALSE;
        }
      }
      return TRUE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Address Windowing Extensions (AWE). For example, you can reserve two regions of virtual memory and then map them to the same physical region one after another. Or you can reserve single virtual region but map different segments of it.

It is not as convenient as Linux mremap, but it works.

Check out Address Windowing Extensions (AWE) please:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366531(v=vs.85).aspx

My working code for your reference based on the MSDN example. Please remember to get the "lock page in memory" privilege for your account in Windows before running it.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define MEMORY_REQUESTED 1024*1024 // request a megabyte

BOOL
LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege(HANDLE hProcess,
    BOOL bEnable);

void _cdecl main()
{
    BOOL bResult;                   // generic Boolean value
    ULONG_PTR NumberOfPages;        // number of pages to request
    ULONG_PTR NumberOfPagesInitial; // initial number of pages requested
    ULONG_PTR *aPFNs;               // page info; holds opaque data
    PVOID lpMemReserved;            // AWE window
    PVOID lpMemReserved2;            // AWE window
    SYSTEM_INFO sSysInfo;           // useful system information
    int PFNArraySize;               // memory to request for PFN array

    GetSystemInfo(&sSysInfo);  // fill the system information structure

    _tprintf(_T("This computer has page size %d.\n"), sSysInfo.dwPageSize);

    // Calculate the number of pages of memory to request.

    NumberOfPages = MEMORY_REQUESTED / sSysInfo.dwPageSize;
    _tprintf(_T("Requesting %d pages of memory.\n"), NumberOfPages);

    // Calculate the size of the user PFN array.

    PFNArraySize = NumberOfPages * sizeof(ULONG_PTR);

    _tprintf(_T("Requesting a PFN array of %d bytes.\n"), PFNArraySize);

    aPFNs = (ULONG_PTR *)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, PFNArraySize);

    if (aPFNs == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Failed to allocate on heap.\n"));
        return;
    }

    // Enable the privilege.

    if (!LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege(GetCurrentProcess(), TRUE))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Allocate the physical memory.

    NumberOfPagesInitial = NumberOfPages;
    bResult = AllocateUserPhysicalPages(GetCurrentProcess(),
        &NumberOfPages,
        aPFNs);

    if (bResult != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot allocate physical pages (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if (NumberOfPagesInitial != NumberOfPages)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Allocated only %p pages.\n"), (void*)NumberOfPages);
        return;
    }

    // Reserve the virtual memory.

    lpMemReserved = VirtualAlloc(NULL,
        MEMORY_REQUESTED,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_PHYSICAL,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (lpMemReserved == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot reserve memory.\n"));
        return;
    }

    lpMemReserved2 = VirtualAlloc(NULL,
        MEMORY_REQUESTED,
        MEM_RESERVE | MEM_PHYSICAL,
        PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (lpMemReserved2 == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot reserve memory.\n"));
        return;
    }

    // Map the physical memory into the window.

    bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages(lpMemReserved,
        NumberOfPages,
        aPFNs);

    if (bResult != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("MapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    else {
        int* pa = (int*)lpMemReserved;
        pa[1] = pa[100] = 0xF0F0;
        _tprintf(_T("MapUserPhysicalPages successfully at %p\n"), lpMemReserved);   
    }


    // unmap

    bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages(lpMemReserved,
        NumberOfPages,
        NULL);

    if (bResult != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("MapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    //remap
    bResult = MapUserPhysicalPages(lpMemReserved2,
        NumberOfPages,
        aPFNs);

    if (bResult != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Re-MapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }
    else {
        int* pa = (int*)lpMemReserved2;
        if(pa[1] != pa[100] || pa[100] != 0xF0F0)
            _tprintf(_T("Re-MapUserPhysicalPages failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
        _tprintf(_T("Re-MapUserPhysicalPages successfully at %p\n"), lpMemReserved2);
    }

    // Free the physical pages.

    bResult = FreeUserPhysicalPages(GetCurrentProcess(),
        &NumberOfPages,
        aPFNs);

    if (bResult != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot free physical pages, error %u.\n"), GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    // Free virtual memory.

    bResult = VirtualFree(lpMemReserved,
        0,
        MEM_RELEASE);

    // Release the aPFNs array.

    bResult = HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, aPFNs);

    if (bResult != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Call to HeapFree has failed (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
    }

    _tprintf(_T("Successfully finished\n"));

}


/*****************************************************************
LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege: a function to obtain or
release the privilege of locking physical pages.

Inputs:

HANDLE hProcess: Handle for the process for which the
privilege is needed

BOOL bEnable: Enable (TRUE) or disable?

Return value: TRUE indicates success, FALSE failure.

*****************************************************************/
BOOL
LoggedSetLockPagesPrivilege(HANDLE hProcess,
    BOOL bEnable)
{
    struct {
        DWORD Count;
        LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES Privilege[1];
    } Info;

    HANDLE Token;
    BOOL Result;

    // Open the token.

    Result = OpenProcessToken(hProcess,
        TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES,
        &Token);

    if (Result != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot open process token.\n"));
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Enable or disable?

    Info.Count = 1;
    if (bEnable)
    {
        Info.Privilege[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    }
    else
    {
        Info.Privilege[0].Attributes = 0;
    }

    // Get the LUID.

    Result = LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL,
        SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME,
        &(Info.Privilege[0].Luid));

    if (Result != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot get privilege for %s.\n"), SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME);
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Adjust the privilege.

    Result = AdjustTokenPrivileges(Token, FALSE,
        (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES)&Info,
        0, NULL, NULL);

    // Check the result.

    if (Result != TRUE)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Cannot adjust token privileges (%u)\n"), GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            _tprintf(_T("Cannot enable the SE_LOCK_MEMORY_NAME privilege; "));
            _tprintf(_T("please check the local policy.\n"));
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(Token);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: I am down-voting this as you seem to assert that more than one virtual page may be mapped to the same physical page. This is not the case and is very likely to blow up in your face (if you even succeed). See [AllocateUserPhysicalPages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366528(v=vs.85).aspx)